# Make Gitlab always use https links?

Tags: gitlab

I just set up a `gitlab-ce` server and I don't have port 80 open on my server. Could I somehow make Gitlab use https in all of its links, including the e-mails?

Comment: Did you even attempt to google this ?

https://www.google.com/search?q=gitlab+https result #1

Comment: @marcolz: apparently I must have misphrased it somehow - I found an answer quickly after posting the question, but hadn't got around to summarizing it there. Thanks for pointing me there anyway ;)